# How do you store the visibility of a form into a variable in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do we check whether a input box is visible or not....then store its state into variable to be outpu via alert ?

right now i'm using and i think it wrong. can any body help ?

```
<input type="hello" name="hello" value="" style="visibility:hidden"/>

function testhideinput(){
            var $input_state = $('input:text[name=hello]').is('visibility');
alert($input_state);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this.

```
var $input_state = $('input:text[name=hello]').is(':visible');
```

That's how it works in my code for a div.

Comment: `:visible` won't work. From the documentation: "Elements with `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` are considered to be visible"

Comment: In that case, it would be a good idea to use `.hide()` instead of setting css property `visibility:hidden` manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputState = $('input:text[name=hello]').css('visibility');

if(inputState == "hidden") {
    // do stuff
}
else {
    // do some other stuff
}
```